# How can I create a new group for items in the Sidebar in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

I have:

- Favorites
- Shared
- Devices

I'd like to create something like:

- Cloud Files

My `Favorites` is getting a little cluttered with shortcuts to a DropBox folder, a SkyDrive folder, a Google Drive folder, an IDrive folder, etc.

How can I create a new group for items in the Sidebar in Finder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can rearrange the order of the three you mentioned though - just click and drag to move them.

A possible workaround would be to create a new folder, say "Cloud files", and put it in the sidebar. You could then place aliases of your other folders into that one. This would help trim down the folders in your Favorites section, as well as keep the same quick access to them.

Comment: A significant motivation for the question, I imagine, is speeding up usability by helping the eyes drill down to a target more quickly—i.e. not just aesthetic "cleanup" but actual performance gain. Grouping into subfolders accomplishes the aesthetic goal but probably worsens usability for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I use a folder named `------------` as a divider. If you need more dividers you could create a new folder inside the first one and so on, be creative!

[image: Screenshot of my setup]

Comment: Alternatively, you can just add an arbitrary number of spaces after the dashes (a different amount of spaces for each folder). That way, you can keep your nice, equally long dividers in one parent folder.

Comment: Shame that this is what we're seemingly stuck with. Nevertheless, to make lemonade of lemons, another natural way to dedupe folder names would be to throw a group name within the dashes as seen in the screenshot (**--- WIP ---**, **--- Folder Actions ---**, **--- Media ---**, **--- Work ---**, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I really can't understand why apple can't implement this, since many finder app alternative have this feature! I don't think it is so difficoult! If it can be of any help to you, I use ForkLift, and it has such feature out of the box